# Redefinition of type in c, but guard is included?

Tags: c, header-files

I have code that I can't compile on one computer. It works on my PC, but on another it doesn't work. The error is "redefinition of typdef cplx" even though I have guard on every header file and I have guard for every definition of typdef:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
typedef std::complex<double> cplx;
#else
#include <tgmath.h>
typedef double complex cplx;
#endif
```

Why this problems occurs?
Here are two header files. blas.h:

```
#ifndef BLAS_H
#define BLAS_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
typedef std::complex<double> cplx;
#else
#include <tgmath.h>
typedef double complex cplx;
#endif
//declaration of functions
#endif
```

and lapack.h:

```
#ifndef LAPACK_H
#define LAPACK_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
typedef std::complex<double> cplx;
#else
#include <tgmath.h>
typedef double complex cplx;
#endif
//declarations of functions
#endif
```

The problem is when I include both, lapack.h and blas.h, I get this error?

Comment: There is no [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in the given sample actually :).

Comment: I included guards on header files. So every header file contains guard at the beginning. Additionally, I have included guards around definition of the type. (like it is described by the code above) .

Comment: @user3616359 Show the code of your header file.

Comment: Usually, when a compiler issues a warning about a redefinition, it shows the line number where the error occurred, and the file/line of the previous definition.

Comment: Yes. It gives on the line where I include lapack.h, and then says that it was previously defined when I include blas.h. But with this guards, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @user3616359 Yup, but as dbush answered, the guards you have only prevent the header files from being included twice. You need a guard that prevents the `cplx` type from being declared twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guards protect against the same include file being included twice, but you have two different include files with two different guards, and you define `cplx` in each one.

You need a separate guard for that type in each include file, like this:

```
#ifndef CPLX
#define CPLX
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
typedef std::complex<double> cplx;
#else
#include <tgmath.h>
typedef double complex cplx;
#endif
//declarations of functions
#endif
```